# Supplement patterns

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have these kind of records in a file:

```
1867    121 2 56 
1868    121 1 6 
1868    121 2 65 
1868    122 0 53 
1869    121 0 41 
1869    121 1 41 
1871    121 1 13 
1871    121 2 194
```

I would like to get this output:

```
1867    121 2 56 
1868    121 1 6 
1868    121 2 65 
1868    122 0 53 
1869    121 0 41 
1869    121 1 41 
1870    121 0 0
1871    121 1 13 
1871    121 2 194
```

The difference is the `1870    121 0 0` row.

So, if the difference between the numbers in the first column is greater than 1, then we have to include a line with the missing number (the above case it is `1870`) and the other columns. One should get the other columns in a way, that let the second column be the minimum of the possible values of the numbers of the column (in the example these values might be `121` or `122`), and for the same as in the third column case. The value of the last column let be always zero.

Can anybody suggest me something? Thanks in advance!

I am trying to solve it with `awk`, but maybe there is (are) other nicer or more practical solution(s) for this...

Comment: You can try solving this with a python script for a "nicer" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work -

```
awk 'BEGIN{getline;a=$1;b=$2;c=$3}
NR==FNR{if (b>$2) b=$2; if (c>$3) c=$3;next} 
{if ($1-a>1) {x=($1-a); for (i=1;i<x;i++) {print (a+1)"\t"b,c,"0";a++};a=$1} else a=$1;print}' file file
```

#### Explanation:

1. **`BEGIN{getline;a=$1;b=$2;c=$3}`** -

   In this **`BEGIN`** block we read the first line and assign values in `column 1` to variable `a`, `column 2` to variable `b` and `column 3` to variable `c`.
2. **`NR==FNR{if (b>$2) b=$2; if (c>$3) c=$3;next}`** -

   In this we scan through the entire file (`NR==FNR`) and keep track of the lowest possible values in `column 2` and `column 3` and store them in variables `b` and `c` respectively. We use `next` to avoid running the second `pattern{action}` statement.
3. **`{if ($1-a>1) {x=($1-a); for (i=1;i<x;i++) {print (a+1)"\t"b,c,"0";a++};a=$1} else a=$1;print}`** -

   This `action` statement checks the for the value in `column 1` and compares it with `a`. If the the difference is more than 1, we do a `for loop` to add all the missing lines and set the value of `a` to `$1`. If the value in `column 1` on successive lines is not greater than 1, we assign the value of `column 1` to `a` and `print` it.

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
1867    121 2 56 
1868    121 1 6 
1868    121 2 65 
1868    122 0 53 
1869    121 0 41 
1869    121 1 41 
1871    121 1 13  # <--- 1870 skipped
1871    121 2 194
1875    120 1 12 # <--- 1872, 1873, 1874 skipped

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'BEGIN{getline;a=$1;b=$2;c=$3}
NR==FNR{if (b>$2) b=$2; if (c>$3) c=$3;next} 
{if ($1-a>1) {x=($1-a); for (i=1;i<x;i++) {print (a+1)"\t"b,c,"0";a++};a=$1} else a=$1;print}' file file
1867    121 2 56 
1868    121 1 6 
1868    121 2 65 
1868    122 0 53 
1869    121 0 41 
1869    121 1 41 
1870    120 0 0 # Assigned minimum value in col 2 (120) and col 3 (0).
1871    121 1 13 
1871    121 2 194
1872    120 0 0 # Assigned minimum value in col 2 (120) and col 3 (0).
1873    120 0 0 # Assigned minimum value in col 2 (120) and col 3 (0).
1874    120 0 0 # Assigned minimum value in col 2 (120) and col 3 (0).
1875    120 1 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution. Should work for large files, too, as it does not load the whole file into memory, but goes over the file two times.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = shift;

open my $IN, '<', $file or die $!;

my @mins;
while (<$IN>) {
    my @cols = split;
    for (0, 1) {
        $mins[$_] = $cols[$_ + 1] if $cols[$_ + 1] < $mins[$_ ]
                                     or ! defined $mins[$_];
    }
}

seek $IN, 0, 0;
my $last;
while (<$IN>) {
    my @cols = split;
    $last //= $cols[0];

    for my $i ($last .. $cols[0]-2) {
        print $i + 1, "\t@mins 0\n";
    }
    print;
    $last = $cols[0];
}
```

Comment: My New Year resolution … **`Learn Perl`** :) … tested your script and works really well. +1

Answer (score 1):

A Bash solution:

```
# initialize minimum of 2. and 3. column
read no min2 min3 c4 < "$infile"

# get minimum of 2. and 3. column
while read c1 c2 c3 c4 ; do
  [ $c2 -lt $min2 ] && min=$c2
  [ $c3 -lt $min3 ] && min=$c3
done < "$infile"

while read c1 c2 c3 c4 ; do
  # insert missing line(s) ?
  while (( c1- no > 1 )) ; do
    ((no++))
    echo -e "$no $min2 $min3 0"
  done
  # now insert existing line
  echo -e "$c1 $c2 $c3 $c4"
  no=$c1
done < "$infile"
```

Comment: Can't you reduce your code in the inner while to `while (( c1-no > 1 )) ; do ... `. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `awk`:

```
BEGIN { 
        if ( ARGC > 2 ) {
                print "Usage: awk -f script.awk <file-name>"
                exit 0
        }

        ## Need to process file twice, duplicate the input filename.
        ARGV[2] = ARGV[1]
        ++ARGC

        col2 = -1
        col3 = -1
}

## First processing of file. Get min values of second and third columns.
FNR == NR {
        col2 = col2 < 0 || col2 > $2 ? $2 : col2
        col3 = col3 < 0 || col3 > $3 ? $3 : col3
        next
}

## Second processing of file.
FNR < NR {
        ## Get value of column 1 in first row.
        if ( FNR == 1 ) {
                col1 = $1
                print
                next
        }

        ## Compare current value of column 1 with value of previous row.
        ## Add a new row while difference is bigger than '1'.
        while ( $1 - col1 > 1 ) {
                ++col1
                printf "%d\t%d %d %d\n", col1, col2, col3, 0
        }

        ## Assing new value of column 1.
        col1 = $1
        print
}
```

Running the script:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

Result:

```
1867    121 2 56 
1868    121 1 6 
1868    121 2 65 
1868    122 0 53 
1869    121 0 41 
1869    121 1 41 
1870    121 0 0
1871    121 1 13 
1871    121 2 194
```